# Evaluate the surface area of the cone delimited by the plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Surface is the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ delimited by the plane $z=0$ and
>   $x+2z=3$.

Well, the first thing I thought is to devide it in two parts, the one that is a simple cone and the other part. But I'm a bit lost of how do I find the proper parametrization for this surface.

Comment: Also relate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587440/how-to-compute-the-area-of-that-portion-of-the-conical-surface-x2y2-z2-whi

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205558/find-the-surface-area-of-the-part-of-the-cone-under-a-plane